# css3 media query and select

Tags: css, media-queries

Not sure how to combine two media queries where one is conditional.

As I am doing it now, I have an entire block of styles duplicated.

The intent:

*If window width < 900px*

**OR**

*if window width < 1300px **ONLY WHEN** html[leng="he"]*

**THEN**

*nav.main's height should be auto (and all the other styles apply too)*

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
        nav.main {
            height: auto;
        }
        ...many more rules
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1130px) {
    html[lang="he"] {
        nav.main {
            height: auto;
        }
        ...identical rules as above
    }
}
```

Any way I can combine these so that the style block is not written twice?

Comment: You should be able to combine these media queries with a comma (and excluding the second @media after concatenating them). See example 6 in the spec for details https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0